# Microsoft.Office.Server dll for getting UserProfiles is missing in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: user-profile, migration

I was migrating my MOSS 2007 project to SharePoint 2010. I am using Microsoft.Office.Server dll for getting user profiles in my code. Now during migration I am getting an exception related to this dll. I went to 14hive\ISAPI to look for this dll in SharePoint Foundation 2010 but can't locate it whereas in MOSS 2007 it was there in the 12\ISAPI folder.

Can you let me know how to resolve this? Do I need to change my code or is there an alternative to Microsoft.Office.server dll in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

I Googled and found out that this dll is present in SharePoint Server 2010 but not in SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Comment: Why are you moving from MOSS (paid) to SharePoint Foundation? why not sharepoint 2010 paid version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This DLL is part of the 'paid' version if SharePoint.

- WSS 3 = SharePoint Foundation (Both free).
- MOSS 2007 = SharePoint Server (Paid).

Comment: So there is no way to make it work .. Is there any hot fix installation for this..

Comment: Yes, by upgrading from Foundation to Server.