# Error while running the Powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I want to run the following script but getting the error `"Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]"`

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("sitenamehere");
$ServiceContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site);

$ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)
$AllProfiles = $ProfileManager.GetEnumerator()

foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)
{
     $Title = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::Title].Value
     $AccountName= $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value
     $PreferredName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::PreferredName].Value

     if( $PreferredName -ne "None" -and $Title -ne $null )
     {
          write-host "Profile: ", $PreferredName,"(",$Title,")"
          $dName = $PreferredName + " (" + $Title + ")"
          #you can add update your users displayname like below
         # Set-SPUser -identity $AccountName -SyncFromAD -web siteURLhere 
     }
}

write-host "Finished."
$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Add-Type cmdlet

> The Add-Type cmdlet lets you define a .NET Framework class in your
>   Windows PowerShell session. You can then instantiate objects (by using
>   the New-Object cmdlet) and use the objects, just as you would use any
>   .NET Framework object. If you add an Add-Type command to your Windows
>   PowerShell profile, the class will be available in all Windows
>   PowerShell sessions.

See full description [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx).

Comment: but I cannot find Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles in my ISAPI dll's /

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you have?

Comment: SharePoint Foundation 2010

Comment: I found [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11876/microsoft-office-server-dll-for-getting-userprofiles-is-missing-in-sharepoint-fo)

Comment: hmmm so its not available in Foundation version